# ContourPlot giving all (most) contours the same shading

Tags: plotting

I am using a ContourPlot command to plot a function and unless I explicitly define the ContourShading I get the same colour used for most intervals.  Is there any way to fix this?

Here's the function that's not doing what I want

```
ContourPlot[1/x 1.303 E^(1/2 (-0.48 (-5.3+x)^2-(137 y^2)/x^2)),
{x,0,15},{y,-2,2},PlotRange->Full,PlotPoints->10,
AspectRatio->1/3,PlotLegends->Automatic]
```

which gives

[image: ContourPlot with same colours]

whereas if I explicitly state the colour shading I get what I expected

```
ContourPlot[1/x 1.303 E^(1/2 (-0.48 (-5.3 + x)^2 - (137 y^2)/x^2)),
 {x, 0, 15}, {y, -2, 2}, 
 PlotRange -> Full, PlotPoints -> 10, 
 AspectRatio -> 1/3, PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
 ContourShading -> {White, Red, Green, Blue, Yellow, Purple}]
```

[image: ContourPlot with each contour a different colour]

If I play around with PlotRange (All, Full, Automatic) then it changes whether I get the contours different colours, but the ranges also change.  Playing around with the number of PlotPoints also changes whether I get contours as expected.

Is this a glitch or expected behaviour?  Is there a way to explicitly tell it to use the default theme?  This is what I was expecting (and have for different parameter values), so I'd like everything to match the same theme.

[image: What I want the figures to look like]

Comment: You have a singularity at {0,0} which is effecting the range used by the color function. If you change the x-range to `{x, 0.1, 15}` you get something that looks reasonable.

Comment: It turns out that all of the colors are actually slightly different, as can be seen if you do `Cases[Normal@plot, RGBColor[a__], Infinity]`.

Comment: Thanks - that has fixed things.  Still seems strange thought that it's not using the same variety in colours that it is later - the largest interval is still kicking in quite early.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is in the option `PlotRange->Full`. By removing this option

```
    ContourPlot[
 1/x*1.303 E^(1/2 (-0.48 (-5.3 + x)^2 - (137 y^2)/x^2)), {x, 0, 
  15}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotPoints -> 10, AspectRatio -> 1/3, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

one immediately gets the different shading:

[image]

Alternatively one may specify the color function:

```
    ContourPlot[
 1/x*1.303 E^(1/2 (-0.48 (-5.3 + x)^2 - (137 y^2)/x^2)), {x, 0, 
  15}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotPoints -> 10, AspectRatio -> 1/3, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

giving the following:

[image]

The white area in the center is related to the default `PlotRange`value, by its fixing we get rid of it:

```
    ContourPlot[
 1/x*1.303 E^(1/2 (-0.48 (-5.3 + x)^2 - (137 y^2)/x^2)), {x, 0, 
  15}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotPoints -> 10, AspectRatio -> 1/3, 
 PlotRange -> {0, 0.3}, PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

[image]

but here the heights are resolved in a more rough way.

Hope it helps. Have fun!

Answer (score 3):

As rcollyer states, you can get the plot you need by leaving the origin out of the plotted range.

```
ContourPlot[
 1/x 1.303 E^(1/2 (-0.48 (-5.3 + x)^2 - (137 y^2)/x^2)), {x, 0.001, 
  15}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotRange -> Full, PlotPoints -> 10, 
 AspectRatio -> 1/3, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

I feel like you should be able to do it using `Exclusions` but I can't quite figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
ContourPlot[
 1/x 1.303 E^(1/2 (-0.48 (-5.3 + x)^2 - (137 y^2)/x^2)), {x, 0.01, 
  15}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotPoints -> 10, AspectRatio -> 1/3, 
 ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Blue, Cyan, Orange, Green, Yellow}, #1] &), 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

Comment: Can you explain what is different in your approach compared to the previous answers?